# PHP foreach SplPriorityQueue - can't find the elements

Tags: php, foreach, priority-queue

I have the following code:

```
    $friendsOrdered= new SplPriorityQueue();
    ... // Code to fill up the priority queue
    print_r($friendsOrdered);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($friendsOrdered as $f) {
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
    print_r($friendsOrdered);
```

When I look at the output of the prints I can see that after the loop the priority queue is empty. Is there a way of stopping the foreach from removing elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot stop the loop from dequeuing elements, as that is the nature of the data structure.  You could, however, create a copy of the object before the loop so your data isn't lost:

```
$friendsOrdered_copy = clone $friendsOrdered;
foreach($friendsOrdered_copy as $f) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: or better iterate over the clone.